# How to implement define interfaces in class library and implement separate process

Tags: .net, interface, c++-cli

I have different interfaces defined in a seperate class library (assembly) and they need to be implemented by classes defined in that process.

The problem is that the interface is defined in a separate class library (assembly) and must be implemented in a different CLR process(assembly). Will adding class library as a reference do the job?

Is there anything else I need to mention in order to tell my classes defined in CLR process (assembly) that classes must implement interfaces which are defined in a seperate Class library (assembly) which's included as reference?

My environment is C++/CLI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to add the class library as a reference to the project. There's nothing more to it than that - just implement the interface as normal.

Note that assemblies *aren't* "CLR processes" - many assemblies are loaded into the same process, and even into the same AppDomain.